# sql query syntax to do with dates

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I am trying to find all users who haven't logged in during the past 30 days, but I am missing something. The idea is to run it every day and generate a file so the today's date will be variable.

I thought this might work, but complains about the use of now.

Thanks in advance.

```
select lastLogin from user.nodes where lastLogin + days < now;
```

Comment: The term you want to Google for is "Google date arithmetic".

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOW` is not a valid Oracle function.  To get the current `date`, use `sysdate`.  If you want to ignore the time component, use `trunc(sysdate)`.  And assuming that `lastLogin` is indexed, you'd want to avoid manipulating `lastLogin` in your query since that prevents the optimizer from using the index.  You'd want to do all your computations on the other side of the predicate.  Putting that together, you probably want something like

```
select lastLogin 
  from user.nodes 
 where lastLogin >= trunc(sysdate) - 30
```

Comment: Ok that helps, but that returns users that logged in today... what about users who's login date is 30 days ago or longer?

Comment: @Jason - Not sure I understand.  `trunc(sysdate)` returns today at midnight.  Subtracting 30 gives you midnight 30 days ago.  Logins more than 30 days ago will be excluded by this query because that's what you asked for initially.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. So what ultimately I would like to do is return all users who haven't logged in 30 days or longer then lock their accounts.

Comment: @Jason - OK.  Is there one row in `user.nodes` for each user?  If so, you would just need to look for rows where `lastLogin <= trunc(sysdate) - 30`.